# Xcode 6 runs Swift app on iOS 7 device and crashed, the console shows log otherApps

Tags: swift, xcode6

**Environment**

Xcode6-Beta4

**Description**

Just created a Single View Controller template iOS App, and runs on iOS 7 device (iPhone 5)
and it just crashed..

```
2014-07-22 13:29:00.211 TimeTracker-iPhone[16701:60b] otherApps (
"com.ketchapp.2048",
"com.google.ios.youtube"
)
```

**The debug stack stop here like this**

```
Thread 1Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x2be7b0c4 in dyld_fatal_error ()
#1  0x2be7bf16 in dyld::halt(char const*) ()
#2  0x2be7d578 in dyld::bindLazySymbol(mach_header const*, unsigned long*) ()
#3  0x2be87fc8 in stub_binding_helper_interface ()
#4  0x0007f0a0 in __arclite_objc_getClass(char const*) at /SourceCache/arclite_iOS/arclite-46/source/arclite.mm:1113
#5  0x0007ec8c in install_bigger_allocateClassPair() [inlined] at /SourceCache/arclite_iOS/arclite-46/source/arclite.mm:1182
#6  0x0007ec70 in __ARCLite__load() at /SourceCache/arclite_iOS/arclite-46/source/arclite.mm:1254
#7  0x39e88266 in call_load_methods ()
#8  0x39e88968 in load_images ()
#9  0x2be7bbbe in dyld::notifySingle(dyld_image_states, ImageLoader const*) ()
#10 0x2be84ce8 in ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) ()
#11 0x2be84b54 in ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) ()
#12 0x2be7bd3c in dyld::initializeMainExecutable() ()
#13 0x2be7eab8 in dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) ()
#14 0x2be7b22e in dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) ()
```

Can't post image now for the limitation

Any idea?

BTW, app runs well on Simulator (7, 7.1)

Comment: Do you have anything else other than the stack?

Comment: what else do you think needed then, as just an empty project create from single view project template?

Comment: Console messages, sorry I wasn't clear

Comment: only the otherApps thing I post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I think I found the root cause, my phone is jailbroken, and have been installed two apps called, AdBlock and AdBlockNetwork, after I remove them, working now...may send a bug ticket to author:)

Comment: Please note that this was not a bug in AdBlock/AdBlockNetwork, but in fact a bug in the Swift toolchain (and thereby a bug in the application) that was fixed in a later release of Xcode. (I have tested 6.0b6 and 6.0.1: the former half-fixed the issue, and the latter seems to have it fully fixed; I don't exactly when it was fixed as I don't have the intermediate versions installed, but I doubt it matters much.)

Answer (score 0):

This same issue affected me.  The issue was that I had deleted a previous failed-attempt, before starting a new project with the same name in the same place.

If this rings any bells, try completely removing the old project by emptying the recycling bin, and then starting your new one under a new name in a new location.

Comment: Hi Hyperion, I cloned my project to my laptop, ran, unfortunately, crashed, same error, of course, same device I'm using

Comment: @xmk Can you just start a new project under a new name and see if the problem persists?  If not, consider copying all files from your original project into the new one

Comment: I think I've found the cause, caused by Adblock, and AdblockNetwork, jailbreak apps